# Getting TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_mathjs.default.fraction'), React-Native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, mathjs

I get this error whenever I use 'mathjs'

**TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_mathjs.default.fraction')**

Basically my code is this

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Button} from 'react-native';
import mathjs from 'mathjs';
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title="TestButton"
        onPress={() => {
           console.log(mathjs.fraction(1, 2)); // equals to ½
         }}
        />
   </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [library's npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjs), I think you need to use a named import, not the default one:

```
import { fraction } from 'mathjs';
```

Named exports won't show up as properties of the default export. You could use this syntax to get all the named exports:

```
import * as mathjs from 'mathjs;
```

Although unless you're actually using them all I don't recommend this, since I think it would defeat tree-shaking for your javascript bundle.

See  [import docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) for more information.

Comment: I was writting this! Dang it!

In a way longer format, tho. I won't drink water next time~

Thank you a lot!